# A question in catkin concepts

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-package, catkin-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am confusing when I read the following part of [Catkin Concepts](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/conceptual_overview)

"A <run_depend> entry will define any dependency that a 3rd package using our new package needs to also have in the environment. This can happen for libraries at runtime, or for headers at build-time of the 3rd package. So "run" in <run_depend> can be slightly misleading. When a debian package is created, it should make sure that all <run_depend> dependencies are also installed by apt-get."

What does it mean a 3rd package?

What I understand about <run_depend> is that it specifies executables or files this new package depends on during run-time. Is it right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52640/a-question-in-catkin-concepts/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assume you build a package like beginner_tutorial. This depends on package roscpp.

This means roscpp is the first package, beginner_tutorial the second.

Now somebody else wants to create another package, additional_stuff, on top of beginner_tutorial. That would be a third package in our dependency chain.

If additional_stuff would also need roscpp to depend on beginner_tutorial, then beginner_tutorial should declare this, so that additional_stuff does not need to declare it as well.

This is not just about run-time, it is about build time of the 3rd package.

E.g. if in beginner_tutorial you create a public c++ header that includes stuff from ros.h (from roscpp), then additional_stuff would need to know where to get ros.h.
So this is not exactly run time.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-17**:
Thank you! I got it!